# Inheritance from a Vpython geometric object

Tags: python, vpython

I am trying to simulate planetary motion using VPython, so I try to write a class "planet" that inherits from the sphere object from the VPython library:

```
class planet(sphere):
    def __init__(self, pos, radius, mass):
        super().__init__(pos, radius)
        mass = self.mass
```

When I try to create some instances from the class:

```
num_planets = 2
positions = [vector(1, 0, 0), vector(-1, 0, 0)]
mass_planet = [1, 100]
planets = [planet(pos = positions[i], radius = 0.5, mass = mass_planet[i]) for i in range(num_planets)]
```

An error is returned:
`TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`

What is happening there?

Comment: The problem is with `sphere`, not `planet`. If `sphere` hasn't defined `__init__`, then `super().__init__` will (or appears to) resolve to `object.__init__`, which doesn't take any parameters other than the object itself.

Comment: I'm not familiar with VPython but try `super().__init__(pos=pos, radius=radius)` if it expects keyword args and not positional ones. Also you probably meant `self.mass = mass` instead of `mass = self.mass`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! So using keyword arguments was the crux of the problem.